# Giving live streamed video as date stamped evidence of an event in court (UK)

Tags: united-kingdom, civil-law, evidence

I am planning on serving a notice to quit directly to my landlord soon, and the plan is to live stream putting the letter in the envelope and posting it at their address, so it's very clear that the content of the letter is what I say it is. This will also prove that I posted the letter on a particular day as well because live streamed videos (on Facebook) are time stamped.

The only issue I have is, when submitting the evidence to the court, the live streamed video will have to be made available to the public for the duration of the trial so that the court can view it, which will of course mean that the name and address of the landlord will be published online.

Are the any legal complications with this? If so, what are the workarounds?

Answer (score 3):

### You can't give your landlord a "notice to quit"

A "notice to quit" is something a landlord gives to the tenant under s8 or s21.

Assuming you want to end the tenancy, you would give them whatever notice is required in accordance with the lease.

### Why the paranoia?

Ending a residential tenancy is routine and would not normally land you anywhere near a court. You give your notice, pay your rent, move out and get your deposit back.

Is there something going on that you're not telling us? If so, ask about that thing in a different question.

### The video would be fine as evidence

However, it would only be used if there was a dispute over the service of the notice. While this can happen, its pretty rare and your precautions seem ... elaborate.

### Your landlord's name and address (and yours) will be a public record forever

Courts are public, the names and addresses of the parties are a matter of public record (unless you are children, or sex offenders, or have some other reason the court accepts as to why this shouldn't happen). These records are kept indefinitely.

Comment: Re notice: assuming it's an assured shorthold tenancy in England or Wales, with rent paid monthly, and **unless it says otherwise**: if you're leaving before the end of a fixed term, [no notice is required](http://england.shelter.org.uk/housing_advice/private_renting/renewing_your_private_tenancy), but is generally appreciated. If it's a rolling tenancy, [one month's notice](https://england.shelter.org.uk/housing_advice/private_renting/ending_a_periodic_tenancy) is required.

Comment: [This page](http://england.shelter.org.uk/legal/security_of_tenure/notices/notices_to_quit/notices_to_quit_tenants) suggests that the notice given by a tenant to the landlord can indeed be referred to as a notice to quit.

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler to just get a process server. Courts tend to give significant deference to process servers, and if a process server says they delivered something, the court will generally take that as fact unless evidence to the contrary is presented.

I don't understand what you mean by "the live streamed video will have to be made available to the public for the duration of the trial so that the court can view it". For the court to view it, you just have to give it to the court. If the court chooses to release it to the public, that's on them, not you.